# get missing height from screensize of website

Tags: javascript, html, css

The website structure would be the following:

1) Topbar

2) Navbar

3) Canvas fitting the missing screen size

4) Bottom bar

---

My problem is the following: How could I get the missing Screen size for the canvas, for example a user opens the site, the topbar got a `height` css attribute which contains: 46px, the navbar got a `height` 46px and the bottom bar: 46px.

How would i get the missing screen size from 100% to fit the whole missing screen, heres a screenshot:

[image]

The red marked area is the missing size which i need to fill the screen.

---

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Could you provide an example in html and css please?

Comment: Only done the half yet, which can be seen here: http://pr0b.com/ sadly never implemented the bottom bar yet.

Comment: I couldn't understand do you want red area height or?
screen.height-document.getElementById('topbar').offsetHeight-document.getElementById('navbar').offsetHeight-document.getElementById('bottombar').offsetHeight;

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you actually need. You can just stick an element in there with height: 100% and it will fill, but if you need to get that number in the JS you'll have to do something like Teymur suggested. Though I would do it with jQuery since you're already using it.

Comment: I want the red areas height

Comment: @d4ne is my answer what you are looking for? or am I confused?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is `vh` it is the view height.

Something like `.contents{width: 100%; height: calc(100vh - 92px)}`

See example https://jsfiddle.net/sxh0n7d1/49/

That will set the div to `100%` of the remaining page after you subtract `92px` for the header and footer.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what i've been searching for.